# Singleton on Two JVM

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is It Possible to achieve Singleton for any given class on two JVM Machine.?
Here My requirement is to achieve Singleton on two JVM machine lets say code is deployed on two machines

Comment: You mean you want to have the same object on 2 JVM? And if one is changes the other change too?

Comment: Implement it as a webservice??  I think some more detail is required here...

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself: why do you need a singleton in the first place? Do you want to share state? If you do, how should concurrency be handled? If you don't, why not create a separate object and not worry about it?

Answer (score 5):

No. The singleton pattern is appliable only for a single JVM.

You can use other approaches (not singleton) to have a single object instance for a number of JVM greater than one.
For that you need a central repository to store information on wich JVM is storing the single instance of your object. This could be a centralized database or a centralized file.

Comment: If you send the object through the  network you will have different equals copies of that object. That is not a singleton. Is a multiple instance of the same object.

Comment: You can obtain the singleton with reflection ,but i think this is not as god as it sounds to send singletons.

Comment: If you send singleton through the network you broke the singleton pattern. The singleton pattern said: "The pattern ensures that only one object of a particular class is ever created"

Comment: In fact, not even in one JVM, only one class loader.

Comment: Correct. More in general singleton is not appliable only to java applications. So it means just one instance in memory per each "environment".

Answer (score 2):

Typically no, but you can implement it in logical way using some kind of distributed caching. E.g. Distributed Ehcache
 (http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.6/get-started/about-distributed-cache)

Here you instantiate the singleton in one JVM and immediately put it in distributed cache which serializes it across all JVMs. So all JVMs have same copy of the singleton (now its no more singleton in theoretical way but logically it is the same object across all JVMs).

Answer (score 0):

No You cannot implement it. totally agree with 
Davide Lorenzo. if you try o do so you will have to either use reflection(a bad way though) or you will break the singleton property.